# multiDimensional Array need as

Tags: php, arrays

Actual array as below is basically the array of $_POST.
One can understand what is coming from the form. three controls with same name different value. What i need is below this array.

```
Array
(
    [mytext] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaaa
            [1] => bbbb
            [2] => ddd
        )

    [mysel] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => two
            [2] => two
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

I need the array in row format below but be dynamic based of $_POST data.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaaa
            [1] => one

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbbb
            [1] => two

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => dddd
            [1] => two

        )


)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$out = Array();
foreach($_POST['mytext'] as $k=>$v) {
    $out[$k] = Array($v,$_POST['mysel'][$k]);
}
var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Code To Get controls value in row wise
$count=0;
foreach($_POST as  $key=>$val){
    foreach($_POST[$key] as $val2){
        $row[$count][]=$val2;
        $count++;
    }
    $count=0;
}
print_r($row);
```

Comment: I have solved in the way above.. any more
good suggestions and examples to do in better way.

Comment: Just an FYI, you can use `$val` instead of `$_POST[$key]`.  You might also want to check if `$val` is an array, so it ignores `submit`.

Comment: good to hear, without the check of array works fine, ignores submit if not an array. Yes it could be $val

Answer (score 0):

Loop through one of the fields, and then pull the corresponding value from the other field.

```
$result = array();
foreach($_POST['mytext'] as $k=>$v){
    $result[] = array($v, $_POST['mysel'][$k]);
}
```

You can also use `array_map` to do this:

```
// PHP 5.3+
$result = array_map(function($a, $b){
    return array($a, $b);
}, $_POST['mytext'], $_POST['mysel']);

// PHP <= 5.2
$result = array_map(create_function('$a,$b', 'return array($a,$b);'), $_POST['mytext'], $_POST['mysel']);
```

Comment: can you explain your code how does this works. I am understanding partially.

Comment: What if more than two elements from post

Comment: The first code block is simple.  It loops over one array, and uses the key to find the corresponding value in the other array(s).  `array_map` is a bit different.  You can pass as many arrays as you want to `array_map`, and it then calls the callback function for each element in each array.  So, to add 3 arrays do `array_map(function($a,$b,$c){},$a1,$a2,$a3);`.